# PyQGIS code for Merge Vector Layers

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, vector, merge

I've been trying to automate the merge vector layers via PyQGIS but I can't seem to get it right. This is my code:

```
import os
import processing 

loc = r"C:\Users\loc"
os.chdir(loc)

shapelist = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

for file in shapelist:
    if "R4A.shp" in file:
        R4A = print(file)

Parameter1 = "QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers"
Parameter2 = "QgsProcessingParameterCrs"
Parameter3 = "QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink"

#parameters = "Parameter1: file1.shp; file2.shp; file3.shp; file4.shp, Parameter2: 'EPSG:4326', Parameter3: r"C:\Users\destination"

processing.run("qgis:mergevectorlayers", parameters)
```

I always get this error:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 4):

The `parameters` should be in dictionary format with the *key* being the name of the algorithm parameter and the *value* being the value. You can set the input layers to be stored in a list when you iterate through your directory, this should make it easier instead of typing each shapefile individually.

So you could use something like the following:

```
import os
import processing 

loc = r"C:\Users\loc"
os.chdir(loc)
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

shapefile_list = []
for file in files:
    if "R4A.shp" in file:
        print(file)
        shapefile_list.append(file)

parameters = {'LAYERS': shapefile_list, 
              'CRS': 'EPSG:4326', 
              'OUTPUT': r"C:\Users\destination\result.shp"}

processing.run("qgis:mergevectorlayers", parameters)
```