# Merging multiple line and point vectors in QGIS 3.28

Tags: pyqgis, vector, merge, vector-layer

I have hundreds of line and vector layers. The line and vector layers are from several kml files. I want to combine the line and point vectors respectively and automatically without having to manually select each point and line in "Merge Vector Layers" menu. The end result would be one line shapefile and one point shapefile. I was thinking of using Python to achieve this, but I don't know where to start. Any idea anyone?[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to clarify what you mean by "merge" -- Append or Union.

Comment: @Vince Thanks a lot, I have clarified the question. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Unioning the points just yields a multi-point, and unioning the lines might not be possible without generating a multipart as well.  A graphic of where you are starting and your goal is critical to solving this. Generally, if you "don't know where to start", GIS SE is not going to be of much help. I'm not going to be giving QGIS instructions.

Comment: @Vince Umm I have no idea about the multipart. The thing is I have multiple point layers  and line layers, and I want to combine them so the end result would be one line shapefile and one point shapefile. The only method I know is using Merge Vector Layers in Data Management Tools.

Comment: did you already search for code, like "merge vector layers pyqgis"?   -> https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/317002/87346

Comment: Selecting the hundreds of files can take a couple of second if you do it right. if your naming is different between line and point they are always displayed sorted by name in the tool so you can use that to separate lines and points and then select all layers of one type in one go. Or you can use the windows (or other os) search function to look for the correct source files when using the "Add File(s)" functionality of the tool.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to use python.

## Modeler

Create a model with a `Multiple Input` Input. Set Allowed layer type to Line:
[image]

When you execute the model only the line layers in your project will be listed, Select All:

[image]

## Python

If you want to use python create three separate [lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp): point/lines/polygons:

[Getting list of only vector layers using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367214/getting-list-of-only-vector-layers-using-pyqgis)

[Filtering layers by geometry type using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377513/filtering-layers-by-geometry-type-using-pyqgis)

```
#Create three empty lists to hold each geometry type
point_list = []
line_list = []
polygon_list = []

for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.type() == QgsVectorLayer.VectorLayer: #To exclude raster layers etc.
        if layer.wkbType()==1:
            point_list.append(layer)
        elif layer.wkbType()==2:
            line_list.append(layer)
        elif layer.wkbType()==3:
            polygon_list.append(layer)
    else:
        print(layer.name(), "is not a vector layer")

print(point_list)
#[<QgsVectorLayer: 'ok_bs_riks' (postgres)>, <QgsVectorLayer: 'ok_gs_riks' (postgres)>, <QgsVectorLayer: 'ok_ns_riks' (postgres)>]
```

Then the easiest it to manually merge for example two point layers through the processing toolbox, then go to processing history and copy the code that was used:

```
processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':['dbname=\'data\' host=localhost port=5432 user=\'postgres\' sslmode=disable key=\'ogc_fid\' srid=3006 type=Point checkPrimaryKeyUnicity=\'1\' table="lmv"."ok_bs_riks" (geom)','dbname=\'data\' host=localhost port=5432 user=\'postgres\' sslmode=disable key=\'ogc_fid\' srid=3006 type=Point checkPrimaryKeyUnicity=\'1\' table="lmv"."ok_gs_riks" (geom)'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

Then modify by replacing the LAYER list with each of your lists it and insert this at the bottom of your code

```
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':point_list,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':line_list,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':polygon_list,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```